# How to use Fira font and mathpazo within the metropolis theme?

Tags: beamer, fonts, mathpazo, beamer-metropolis

I am trying to use the Fira font within the metropolis presentation theme for the text and the mathpazo font for the math mode. How can I do this?

My MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme 
\usepackage{FiraSans}
\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{First Frame}
 Hello, world! Here some random math:
 \begin{equation*}
 s_{t}=\begin{cases}
 \bar{s}, & t\in \left\lbrace 0,\dots, T-1\right\rbrace  \\
 \tilde{s}, & t\geq T
 \end{cases}
 \end{equation*} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

This results in:

[image]

The math stuff does not have the shape of the usual mathpazo font.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What engine are you using when compiling the document? You should be using PDFLaTeX!

Comment: I compiled with XeLaTeX because it was suggested by metropolis. However, it works with pdfLaTeX! Thanks!

Comment: The problem is `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}`.  I'm not exactly sure why it's conflicting, but using `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` will give you basically the same output with pdfLaTeX or XeLaTeX.  The latter font theme has slightly different spacing, it seems.  Former is more condensed and latter more expanded.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### In the Modern Toolchain

I personally recommend you use `unicode-math` when you can, and legacy fonts when you have to.  Not everyone agrees, so I present the alternatives.

With the package `unicode-math`, you can use any OpenType fonts of your choice, including Fira Sans and its successor [FiraGO](https://github.com/bBoxType/FiraGO).  Asana Math is a Unicode math font based on `mathpazo`, but with many more symbols.  There is, additionally, an experimental [Fira Math](https://github.com/firamath/firamath) font for use with `unicode-math`, but as of 2019, it is a work in progress.

This example additionally sets all letters and numerals in math mode to Fira Sans.  You could change this to FiraGO as well, if you wanted.  It supports the mathematical Greek OpenType feature.

```
\documentclass[10pt]{beamer}

\useinnertheme{metropolis}
\useoutertheme{metropolis}
\usecolortheme{metropolis}
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale = MatchUppercase }
\setmainfont{FiraGO}[Scale = 1.0]
\setsansfont{FiraGO}
\setmonofont{Fira Mono}
\setmathfont{Asana Math}
\setmathfont[range=up]{Fira Sans Regular}
\setmathfont[range=it]{Fira Sans Italic}
\setmathfont[range=bfup]{Fira Sans Bold}
\setmathfont[range=bfit]{Fira Sans Bold Italic}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}{Math}
  \begin{equation*}
    \symup{e} = \lim_{n\to \infty} \left(1 + \frac{1}{n}\right)^n
  \end{equation*}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image: Math Sample]

Note that you want to enable `\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}` for certain math features to work (such as the resized parentheses in this example). Therefore, I overrode all the fonts.  The `metropolis` theme also allows you to select the color theme of your choice.

### Mixing OpenType with Legacy Math Fonts

If you want to use a legacy NFSS math package, such as `mathpazo`, or its successor `newpxmath`, or the sans-serif modification `newtxsf`, load the math package and use `mathastext`.

With XeLaTeX, you have the option to load `mathspec` and `\setmathsfont{Fira Sans}` or `\setmathsfont{FiraGO}`.

Or see @samcarter’s excellent answer.

### Using only Legacy Fonts

You do not need to do this if you are using `metropolis`, but for completeness, you can also do this in PDFLaTeX:

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[sfdefault,scaled=.85]{FiraSans}
\usepackage{newtxsf}
```

Answer (score 7):

As long as the metropolis theme is compiled with a suitable engine (e.g. xelatex) it uses fira fonts per default. So simply do not load any other packages or themes and you'll get fira font for text.

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex

\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme{metropolis} % Use metropolis theme 


\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif} 
\usepackage{mathpazo}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}{First Frame}
 Hello, world! Here some random math:
 \begin{equation*}
 s_{t}=\begin{cases}
 \bar{s}, & t\in \left\lbrace 0,\dots, T-1\right\rbrace  \\
 \tilde{s}, & t\geq T
 \end{cases}
 \end{equation*} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

A version of the math font which plays nicer with xelatex:

```
% !TeX TS-program = xelatex
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{moloch}% modern fork of the metropolis theme
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setsansfont{Fira Sans Light}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}

\begin{document}
 \begin{frame}
 \frametitle{First Frame}
 Hello, world! Here some random math:
 \begin{equation*}
 s_{t}=\begin{cases}
 \bar{s}, & t\in \left\lbrace 0,\dots, T-1\right\rbrace  \\
 \tilde{s}, & t\geq T
 \end{cases}
 \end{equation*} 
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: OP said "The math stuff does not have the shape of the usual mathpazo font." and the screenshots looked like Fira was used for non-math mode.  I think OP was talking about wanting standard italics when s/he wrote "the shape of the usual mathpazo font".  For some reason italics appear with `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` with pdfLaTeX but non-italics with XeLaTeX.

Comment: @whatisit In the image of the OP the "math stuff" looked like the computer modern serif font, not `mathpazo`. `\usefonttheme[onlymath]{serif}` will result in math italic for both pdflatex and xelatex, just the font is different.

Comment: When I compile this with pdfLaTeX, I get italics in math.  When I compile it with XeLaTeX, I do not have italics in math (and get the same as in OP's screenshot).  Maybe it *should* be italic in both...but in practice that is not what I am seeing.

Comment: @whatisit The missing math italic is a consequence of the encoding. `mathpazo` would need `T1` or `OT1`, but this would kind of invalid all the advantages of using xelatex. ... If math italic is a must, I suggest to use `\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}` instead of mathpazo

Comment: Ok, thanks for the details.  I am did not look into `mathpazo` fonts, so hadn't noticed this requirement.  Thanks for including the alternate version!

Comment: Some things in math mode break if you load `unicode-math` without `]usefonttheme{professionalfonts}`. For example `\left( \right)`.

Comment: @Davislor Thanks a lot for your comment, I added the `professionalfonts` theme. Happy new year!